# spring-integration-kafka message-driven-channel-adapter XML config

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am trying to write an app to consume messages from Kafka topic and then enrich the inbound message to add new headers. The versions in use are:

```
spring-integration-core  -- 5.3.4.RELEASE
spring-integration-kafka -- 3.3.1.RELEASE
spring-boot              -- 2.3.5.RELEASE
```

When in my integration XML, `int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter` doesn't allow me to supply an output channel or channel property. I am not sure how to tie this to next channel in the flow which can be a `router`, `transformer`, `enricher`, or anything else for that matter.

This is a sample app that will just receive a message from Kafka topic, do some transformation, enrichment, etc. and then persist the parts of message in the database.

Can you please give some XML config template for a multi-channel integration?

For the sake of completion, here's what I am trying but not able to proceed further:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:int-ftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp"
    xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:int-jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"
    xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp/spring-integration-ftp.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">
    
    <int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
        listener-container="messageListenerContainer"
        send-timeout="5000"
        mode="record"
        retry-template="template"
        recovery-callback="callback"
        error-message-strategy="ems"
        error-channel="errorChannel" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you having a runtime problem or an IDE problem?

There's a test case that has a `channel` property.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/15c2d16866a72470b35c65a34e869998f5823f81/spring-integration-kafka/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/kafka/config/xml/KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterParserTests-context.xml#L12-L23

I am seeing some false errors in eclipse right now; investigating...

**EDIT**

If you are using Spring Tool Suite 4, XML namespace support is disabled by default.

Enabling it solved the problem for me, but I had to restart the IDE.

[image]

Comment: These are the only properties available when I do a Ctrl + Spacebar in eclipse IDE

<int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
 message-converter=""
 payload-type=""
        listener-container="messageListenerContainer"
        send-timeout="5000"
        mode="record"
        retry-template="template"
        recovery-callback="callback"
        error-message-strategy="ems"
        error-channel="errorChannel" />

Hevn't yet tried running this as I am still doing some initial design and got hung up on how to tie channels.

Comment: Don't put code in comments; it doesn't render well. You can ignore the errors, I am investgating why we are seeing these false errors.

Comment: See the edit to my answer; XML namespace support is disabled by default in Spring Tool Suite 4.

Comment: I am using eclipse Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0), Build id: 20200910-1200 and the default installation; no plugins added. The default JDK is 15 but the compiler compliance setting is at 1.8. If it is an IDE issue, I will try to fix it myself. I raised this question wondering why this is not working when all examples are using these properties.

Comment: You need to add the Spring Tools plugins (or use Spring Tool Suite which is based on eclipse and already has them installed). Vanilla eclipse doesn't know anything about Spring or Spring Configuration files. https://spring.io/tools

Comment: Installing STS 4.0 in eclipse worked. Thanks for your support